# React Native: Unable to load source map

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I create a project on react native and bundle for my iPhone device. 
I have that warning:

```
Unable to load source map: no source map URL found. May be running from bundled file
```

What is it? How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I once tried React apps but not so into iOS level designing React Apps. but someone sure help you here, if you had detailed explain about your issue.

i just copy / Pasted your statement in Google and found the chances of your issue.

As a JavaScript background, i can say

1. It may be caused by inappropriate connection to modules you specified.
2. And from this [git issue post](https://github.com/este/este/issues/752)  you can come to certain extent of your problem/
3. if you are using any babel or webpack tools check the complete steps what you wrote their once ( or check even you copied from some where ).

And be conscious while asking questions in stack overflow. cause if you are lucky your question may not get any response and dumped to un-answered question pile  or in other case you will get bunch of negative marks for your question and gets ban to several areas of your participation in this Contribution portal [ like ME ] .. so roam around here to get to know about Stack overflow [question polices](https://stackoverflow.com/help)